# HTML tags enable in Default tooltip labels in chart.js

Tags: html, angularjs, tooltip, chart.js, angular-chartist.js

Need to add HTML tags in default `tooltip` in label `callback function`

```
tooltips: { 
    callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
            return "<h1>Daily Ticket Sales</h1> </br> $" + tooltipItem.yLabel;
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I can see that you want to give some style or to increase the font size of '**Daily Ticket Sales**'. One thing that you can do is to put the title in the title callback and change the style for the title through tooltip properties.
[**Sample-Code**]

```
options: {
            tooltips: {
                titleFontSize : 24,
                callbacks: {
                    title: function(tooltipItems, data) {
                        return 'Daily Ticket Sales';
                    },
                    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                        return '$'+tooltipItem.yLabel;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Now you see I set the title font size to 24. So that, it will start giving look of h1. Below are the properties that you set for the tooltip title.

```
titleFontStyle
titleSpacing
titleMarginBottom
titleFontColor
titleAlign
```

Comment: Thanks @Sanjay  for your reply and how i add `<br>` tags and some other **html tags** in label callback ?